# `evm_increaseTime` does not increase timestamp

Tags: testrpc

How can I fix this?

See:

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getBlock("latest").timestamp
> 1506694386
truffle(development)> web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [500000], id: 123})
{ id: 123, jsonrpc: '2.0', result: 500000 }
truffle(development)> web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [500000], id: 123})
{ id: 123, jsonrpc: '2.0', result: 1000000 }
```

When using `evm_increaseTime`, the result returns a value that appends to 0, instead of adding onto the block time.

The expected `result` value should be 1506694386 + 500000, but instead, it returns 0 + 500000.

### Your Environment

- Version used: v4.1.3
- Operating System and version: Mac OSX

---

**EDIT: On the suggestion of force-mining:**

If I mine a block before (or even after) performing `evm_increaseTime`, it does not make a difference:

```
$ truffle console
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getBlock("latest").timestamp
1506739091
truffle(development)> web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_mine", params: [], id: 0})
{ id: 0, jsonrpc: '2.0', result: [] }
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getBlock("latest").timestamp
1506739124
truffle(development)> web3.eth.getBlock("latest").timestamp
1506739124
truffle(development)> web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [500000], id: 123})
{ id: 123, jsonrpc: '2.0', result: 500000 }
truffle(development)> web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_mine", params: [], id: 0})
{ id: 0, jsonrpc: '2.0', result: [] }
truffle(development)> web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_increaseTime", params: [500000], id: 123})
{ id: 123, jsonrpc: '2.0', result: 1000000 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the testrpc docs  https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc :

> evm_increaseTime : Jump forward in time. Takes one parameter, which is the amount of time to increase in seconds. Returns the total time adjustment, in seconds.

So it's normal that the first call you make returns 500000 and the second call returns the total time adjustment 500000 + 500000 = 1000000.

To make those adjustments effective you need to force a block to be mined after you've ran evm_increaseTime :

```
web3.currentProvider.send({jsonrpc: "2.0", method: "evm_mine", params: [], id: 0})
```

afterwards you can check the current timestamp with:

`web3.eth.getBlock(web3.eth.blockNumber).timestamp`

Comment: Not working, see my edit.

Comment: So the right order of things is : evm_increaseTime -> evm_mine -> check timestamp .   In your edited example you're not checking the time stamp after running evm_increaseTime and evm_mine , you need to check the timestamp as the last step

Comment: you are right! working now.

Answer (score 0):

`result` field in response to `evm_increaseTime` call contains timestamp adjustment, not timestamp of the next block.

Check the [source code](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/commit/8d373d97700c618f0a68c253803be6d4f1153cee#diff-8f55aa0c345972c969bb69ce03983e2dR436):

```
BlockchainDouble.prototype.increaseTime = function(seconds) {
  if (seconds < 0) seconds = 0;
  this.timeAdjustment += seconds;
  return this.timeAdjustment;
};
```