# In truffle5, how to manipulate time with evm_increaseTime?

Tags: solidity, truffle, time

I am using truffle 5 and ganache-cli. I've imported increaseTime as

```
import increaseTime from './helper/increaseTime';
```

and the increaseTime.js file is like this

```
export default function increaseTime(addSeconds) {
  const id = Date.now();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
      jsonrpc: '2.0',
      method: 'evm_increaseTime',
      params: [addSeconds],
      id,
    }, (err1) => {
      if (err1) return reject(err1);

      web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
        jsonrpc: '2.0',
        method: 'evm_mine',
        id: id + 1,
      }, (err2, res) => (err2 ? reject(err2) : resolve(res)));
    });
  });
}
```

I am trying to use change the time to insert the follow code

```
await increaseTime(24 * 60 * 60);
```

But I've got error message,

*TypeError: web3.currentProvider.sendAsync is not a function*

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync` to `web3.currentProvider.send`

With truffle 5 you are using web3 1.0. However, the `sendAsync` is the legacy function of 0.20.

Comment: BTW, `web3.currentProvider.send` also works in Truffle 4.x (web3 0.x, as you mentioned), so your solution is compatible with both versions.

Comment: changing "sendAsync" to "send" gives me `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function`

Comment: @Jim i got the same error, have you find any solution?

Comment: Maybe try to change `web3.currentProvider.send.bind(web3.currentProvider)`?

Comment: @gabkov To fix the "callback is not a function" you need to pass a second parameter to the "send" function because the newer version of it takes a function as its second parameter.  Example:        <code> web3.currentProvider.send({
      jsonrpc: "2.0", 
      method: "evm_increaseTime", 
      params: [864000], 
      id: 0
    },(err1) => {
      if(err1){
        return reject(err1);
      }
    });</code>